# Cookie is display in the address bar when redirect 302

Tags: jsf, session, cookies, weblogic

I'd like to know why the cookie is shown in the address bar when I access my application for the first time? For security reason I'd like to hide the cookie from the address bar.

As you can see from the files below when you access the application, you first start by calling `index.html`, then you're redirected to `home.xhtml`, and because you haven't got a session yet you're redirected to `login.jsp`. Not always but sometimes you can see the cookie in the address bar.

> https://X.X.X.X:7111/app/faces/jsp/login.jsp;COOKIE_APP=dNVrSTPhjW8ThySgwtqKJZSfT318zXNWt00P3K1wNBhy3TWmnP5Q!1315530522

- Question 1: Why sometimes the cookie is shown is the address bar and sometimes not?
- Question 2: How can I get rid of the cookie in the address bar? (doing POST indeed but how?)

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=faces/content/home.xhtml">
</head>

<body bgcolor="white">
</body>
</html>
```

**web.xml**

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/faces/jsp/login.jsp</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/faces/jsp/loginretry.jsp</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
```

Comment: The container does that if it can't set the cookie response header for some reason which you've to determine yet.